# How to use returned value/s in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I currently have the following service:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class UserServiceService {
  userEmail: string;
  userPassword: string;

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

  login( userEmail, userPassword ){
    let body = { "email": userEmail, "password": userPassword};

    this.http.post('/customer/service/logging', body, httpOptions).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log( data );
      },
      error => {
        console.error("There Is Something Wrong\nPlease Try Again Later...");
      }
    );

  }
}
```

At run-time the post, if successful, returns the following object:

```json
{message: "Login Successful", status: "success"}
```

What I want to do is to take the key status and use it for routing (if
successful), then the key message to alert the user that his/her login
went successfully / not.

How can I take this keys and values and use them, as mentioned above?

Comment: you can use "canActivate" route guards for that.

Comment: Please provide me with example on regards to the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.http.post('/customer/service/logging', body, httpOptions).subscribe(
  data => {
    if(data.status === 'success'){
        alert(data.message); //or do whatever you want 
     }else {
     alert('login fails'); // or alert(data.message) with the error message from the server
    }
  },
  error => {
    console.error("There Is Something Wrong\nPlease Try Again Later...");
  }
);
```

Comment: data.status gives me an error, is there any imports I have to make?

Comment: use `console.log(data)` to check the object you're returning from the server...if it is indeed what you mentioned, `data.status` wouldn't give an error

Comment: I know why it was screaming; it wanted the http to have a return, for e.g. this.http.post<any>('/customer/se...

Comment: but typing the method is not mandatory, why is asking you to type it? in any case...did you manage to access data.status?

Answer (score 0):

you should convert it to json at first

```
this.http.post('/customer/service/logging', body, httpOptions)
.subscribe(
  data => {
    let res = data.json();
    console.log( res.status);

  },
  error => {
    console.error("There Is Something Wrong\nPlease Try Again Later...");
  }
);
```

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, `HttpClient` does not need the `map` function anymore.

Comment: Yep, that's what the doc says